# Tilda - изменить ссылку кнопки

Tags: html, css

Есть сайт на Tilda. Есть блок ST310N или же каталог товаров. Когда нажимаю на товар высвечивается галерея товара(или же подробное описание, попап), там есть кнопка добавить в корзину. Как изменить ссылку этой кнопки?

В добавок скажу, что там можно изменить название этой кнопки, а вот как изменить ссылку для меня загадка... В поддержке ответили, что сделать это можно только через сторонний код.
Также скажу, что можно добавить кастомный html код на страницу.
[image: этой кнопке нужно изменить href]